# How to get values returned by child action method in mvc 5 partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying not very successfully to get my head around MVC. My home controller contains an Index method that runs OK, so far so good, but I don't know how to call the ChildAction method Home/TopArticle

**Action Method**

```
[ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult TopArticle()
{
    return PartialView(_service.GetTopArticle());
}
```

In my Index view I have the mark up:

```
@section featured {
    @Html.Partial("_TopItem")
}
```

**_TopItem View**

```
@model IEnumerable<MySite.Models.NewPage>

<section class="featured">
    <div id="TopItem">
            <div id="TopItemImg">
                <a href="http://www.mysite.co.uk/">
                    <img style="border: 1px solid lightgray" width="320" height="233" style="border:1px solid lightgray;" alt="Model.Title" src="/Img/Model.TopItemImage">
                </a>
            </div>
            <div id="TopContent">
                <h2><a href="/Home/TopItem/Model.Id/Model.Title"></a></h2>
                <div class="dt">
                    <div class="dl">
                        @Html.Label(Model.DatePublished.ToString())
                        @Html.Label(@Html.Action("TopArticle", "Home", new { // am lost at this point}))
                    </div>
                    <div class="tl">
                        @Html.Label(Model.InfoTags ?? "")
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
</section>
```

The Index view is also using @model IEnumerable and I don't actually know whether that's OK or not. The model itself contains everything needed for both the Index and the _TopItem views, it's just that there will be one record returned for the _TopItem view and many for the Index view. Plus the code that runs in _service.GetTopArticle does some non-query stuff that is relevant only for the top article record.

I need a lie down ... and time to learn this stuff properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, regarding your question about calling the child action from your Index view:

Your featured section is currently calling `@Html.Partial` which means that it will find the `"_TopItem"` partial view and render it as an html encoded string in the current view (i.e. your Index view).

You specified that you are trying to call the child action `TopArticle()` and render the partial view returned as a html string in the view.  To do this you would need to use:

```
@section featured {
    @Html.Action("TopArticle", "Home")
}
```

However, I don't believe this is what you do need as you said that your Index view model contains all of the information for both Index and for the _TopItem partial view (see later).

For more information you should do a google search about the differences of views, partial views and child actions.

To correct the code I would start off by ensuring that the _TopItem partial view is correct.  I have identified the following issues with the _TopItem partial view, some of which are beyond the scope of the original question:

- The model passed in as an IEnumerable of NewPage but your code does not enumerate over several new page objects, it looks like it should just create the html for a single NewPage model.  Therefore, I believe the model declaration should be:

  ```
  @model MySite.Models.NewPage
  ```
- The  tag contains 2 references to the style attribute rather than 1.
- The  tag contains the alt attribute of `alt="Model.Title"` which means that `alt="Model.Title"` will be written directly as html where I expect you would like `alt="@Model.Title"` to render the contents of the model in the alt attribute.
- Similarily, the  tag contains `src="/Img/Model.TopItemImage"` where I expect this should be `src="/Img/@Model.TopItemImage"`
- All of the label tags appear to be incorrect.  For example, `@Html.Label(Model.DatePublished.ToString())` - `Model.DatePublished.ToString()` will return a string and this string will then be attempted to be found on the model and will error as that field name does not exist.  Therefore, you probably want to write: `@Html.Label("DatePublished")` or `@Html.Label(m => m.DatePublished)`.  With the second label i'm not sure what your trying to achieve but you may want to look up the appropriate articles.

Once, you have the corrected _TopActicle partial view, you can then return to your Index view to render the partial directly:

```
@section featured {
    @Html.Partial("_TopItem", Model.TopArticle)
}
```

Note, as you have said that your Index model contains the information to pass to the _TopItem partial view, I have assumed that the Index model contains a property called TopArticle of type NewPage.  Regardless, you can pass the model into the partial however you find appropriate through the call to @Html.Partial.  If you pass the model through the call to @Html.Partial then you may not need the ChildOnlyAction.

Comment: Thanks for such a thorough answer, sorry about delay in replying.